# Select and select Count (aggregate & non aggregate in same query)

Tags: sql-server

I have the script below. The output is XML data in Row/Column format. Also with a variable [Name].

At this moment I only use a select statement. What I need is that sum of some columns (not all) in the select statement

The columns that needs to be Totals are: ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC

The script:

```
;With CTE
AS
(
SELECT [Month]
,[Name]
,[Month_Code]
,[ColumnA]
,[ColumnB]
,[ColumnC]
FROM Fact_A
INNER JOIN Dim_A on Fact_A.Key = Dim_A.Key
INNER JOIN Dim_B on Fact_A_Key = Dim_B.Key
WHERE Fiscal_Year = '20132014'
)

select [Name] AS [@name],
(select [Month] as [column],
null as tmp,
ColumnA as [column],
null as tmp,
ColumnB as [column],
null as tmp,
ColumnC as [column]
from CTE
where [Name] = t.[Name]
Order BY [Month_Code]

for xml path('row'),type) as [*]
from (select distinct [Name] from CTE)t
for xml path('variable'),root('data')
```

Comment: what Database is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you want the TOTALS of these colums per cluster and month, then you could try:

```
SELECT Month
,Name
,Month_Code
,SUM(ColumnA) AS A
,SUM(ColumnB) AS B
,SUM(ColumnC) AS C
FROM Fact_A
INNER JOIN Dim_A on Fact_A.Key = Dim_A.Key
INNER JOIN Dim_B on Fact_A_Key = Dim_B.Key
GROUP BY Month, Name, Month_Code
WHERE Fiscal_Year = '20132014'
```

If you do not want to sum all your columns you could use another Aggregate instead of SUM(), e.g. COUNT() or MAX() for any of the columns

Comment: Thanks, but does not work, error: Column 'CDM_Dim_Date.Month' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Are you sure you took the latest version, since I added Month to the GROUP BY clause, it is not likely that the same error persists

Comment: Really sorry, I forgot the GROUP BY . I am going to check it again. one moment please